# How to use groupBy on a list of tuples?

Tags: haskell

How can I group this list by second element of tuples:

```
[(3,2),(17,2),(50,3),(64,3)]
```

to get something like:

```
[[(3,2),(17,2)],[(50,3),(64,3)]]
```

I'm actually a newcomer to Haskell...and seems to be falling in love with it. Hope you would help me find an efficient way.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you've already identified that you want [`Data.List.groupBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy). The type of this function is

> ```
> groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
> ```

So it takes a binary predicate, i.e. an equivalence relation determining how to group elements. You want to group elements by equality on the second term of a pair, so you want

```
groupBy (\x y -> snd x == snd y) myList
```

Where `snd` is a built-in function that gets the second element of a pair.

Incidentally, this pattern of "apply a function to two arguments and then apply a binary function to the results" is *very* common, especially when calling `Data.List` functions, so `Data.Function` provides [`on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on).

> ```
> on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
> ```

Weird signature, but the use case is just what we want.

> ```
> ((+) `on` f) x y = f x + f y
> ```

So your desired `groupBy` can be written as

```
groupBy ((==) `on` snd)
```

Note that `groupBy` only finds *consecutive* equal elements. You didn't indicate whether you wanted consecutive equal elements or *all* equal elements, but if you want the latter, then I don't believe Haskell `base` provides that function, though you could certainly write it recursively yourself.

Comment: For non-consecutive grouping you can just use `sortBy` before doing `groupBy`.